# Is it possible to install Xcode on iPad for iOS apps developemnt?

Tags: ipad, xcode4.2

Can we develop iOS apps for iPhone as well as iPad using iPad itself?

Comment: Please re-open.  This is now possible using cloud-driven apps like Dringend (http://dringend.cc/).

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to install Xcode on iPad for iOS apps developemnt?

No, Xcode runs on OS X only.

> Can we develop iOS apps for iPhone as well as iPad using iPad itself?

Yes, we can, at least if targeting jailbroken devices is an option. There's an on-device toolchain that you can build following [this tutorial](http://leoth3o.wordpress.com/building-llvm-gcc/), for example.

Comment: +1 for the better answer.

Comment: @0x7fffffff Thanks! You should know that I am developing this way :)

Comment: Interesting. Isn't that painful?

Comment: @0x7fffffff No, in fact, Xcode is so awful that I actually *prefer* this method :) If you have a good text editor with syntax highlighting and a build automation tool (such as `make`), then nothing is painful, really.

Comment: I'll have to give that a try some time. Too bad my iPad is beta'd out at the moment, and to be honest I still haven't even looked up if iOS 7 has been jailbroken yet... :p

Comment: @0x7fffffff Definitively give it a go. Don't upgrade to a beta, though. It's not worth the pain :)