# iPhone app developed with PhoneGap emulated on an iPad

Tags: iphone, cordova, ipad, ios-simulator

## Background

Using Xubuntu Linux distro with [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to write an iPhone (and Android) app.

I only own a first generation iPad (iOS 5.x); I neither own nor wish to procure more Apple devices; additionally, I do not want to pay for third-party software.

## Problem

PhoneGap provides an [iOS simulator](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim), which [requires](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html) Xcode 6+ (previously 4.5+). The Xcode software requires an Apple device.

### Attempted Solutions

VirtualBox can run Hackintosh, but that solution is painfully slow, and buggy.

QEMU/KVM can also run Mac OS X, but the configuration and setup is daunting and overwhelmingly complex.

Using a [jailbroken iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18257125/59087) might make it possible to run Xcode, but I'd rather not jailbreak the iPad.

## Questions

Can I leverage the iPad to simulate an iPhone to run the app?

- Note: The **alternative solution** from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19490759/59087) implies that the iPad might not be necessary, which conflicts with the aforementioned documentation.

If leveraging the iPad for testing purposes is possible, then is it also possible to submit the app to the App store via the iPad?

Comment: This might be better asked on Programmers SE...

Comment: In Xcode is a setting for choosing the deployment device, there you can switch between iPad and iPhone. I just had a look in the Xcode files, but I can't find the settings there in a file. Maybe you search for it. BUT: If you want to submit the app to the store, you need Xcode and it could be that Apple is checking your development machine.

Comment: Thanks, Jeorg. Perhaps the question is unclear. I don't want to switch between an iPad or an iPhone as the type of app to deploy. I own an iPad and want to make an iPhone app -- is that possible? (I don't currently have Xcode on the iPad; I don't enjoy using Macs and an iPad is no substitute for a development machine.)

Comment: My answer was unclear, sorry: You can simulate an iPhone on an iPad a little bit, but that it is nothing for really developing, don't choose this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

You cannot use a first generation iPad to simulate an iPhone.

## Alternate Solution

You can avoid the buggy and sluggish Xcode environment under VirtualBox by using PhoneGap and ios-sim. The solution comes in the following parts:

- Install and configure VirtualBox
- Install development software on VirtualBox
- Test new project
- Perform development work-flow

### Configure VirtualBox

Create and configure VirtualBox as follows:

1. Install VirtualBox 5.0.2 (or greater) from [Oracle](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
2. Download the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack (to enable USB 2.0).
3. Install the Extension Pack from **File >> Preferences >> Extensions**.
4. [Install](http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/11/how-to-install-os-x-yosemite-on-your-pc-with-yosemite-zone.html) Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite using VirtualBox 5.0.2.
5. Press F8 during the boot sequence to set the kernel parameters, such as:

   `/amd busratio=11 colors=32`

Calculate `busratio` by dividing cpu MHz by 133 and rounding. For example, an AMD running at 1.4 GHz is `1400 MHz / 133 = 10.52 = 11`. Note: The `/amd` is only required during installation for AMD processors and must be omitted on normal start up. On Linux, you can `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to verify the processor type.

### Install Development Software

Continue as follows:

1. Install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/download/).
2. Install [Xcode 6+](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/).
3. Install [PhoneGap Desktop](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/desktop-app/install/mac/) (might not be required).
4. Open a terminal.
5. Install PhoneGap command-line interface (CLI):

   `sudo npm install -g phonegap`
6. Install iOS simulator:

   `sudo npm install -g ios-sim`
7. Optionally, verify the simulator works (use docker icon to stop the simulator):

   `ios-sim start`
8. Enable Developer Mode:

   `DevToolsSecurity -enable`

### Test Project

Create, build, and run a new project, which will contain a Hello World example. From the open terminal:

```
phonegap create project
cd project
phonegap build ios
ios-sim launch ./platforms/ios/build/emulator/Hello\ World.app
```

### Development Work-flow

The development work-flow follows:

1. Make changes in Xubuntu Linux.
2. Commit changes into repository.
3. Switch to Virtual Machine.
4. Pull changes from repository.
5. Build.
6. Close iOS Simulator.
7. Re-run ios-sim to see new updates.

You can now develop and preview your apps.

## Legalities

Although the software is [available at no charge](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/os-x-yosemite/id915041082?mt=12), see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107376/143714) for hardware license details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PhoneGap app on iOS and Android to simulate the your app on devices using local server, more info here on how to setup: http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/23/phonegap-developer-app/

Comment: It appears as though the PhoneGap app only supports iOS 6. The iPad I own is gen 1. The older version of PhoneGap app that is compatible with iOS 5.x does not work.